# How do I create new excel sheets within a for loop?

Tags: python, excel, for-loop, xlwt

so I have a code which calculates some values from a data frame and writes it into an excel sheet.

Now, I am looking for a way to run a for loop and for each iteration create a new
excel sheet and write the values in a new sheet.

To illustrate this, here is a minimal example, where the code inside the loop is just deviding the number by 2.

```
import pandas as pd

import xlwt 
from xlwt import Workbook

wb = Workbook()
l = []

for number in range(5):
    value = number/2
    l.append(value)
```

The output which is appended to the list `l` is : `[0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0]`

(appending the values to the list is not needed for me just so that I can show the  values generated form each iteration)

My question would be how could I write each value into a separate sheet.

To do so I tried running these lines inside the loop:

```
sheet1 = wb.add_sheet('sheet1')
sheet1.write(0, 0, value)
```

However this gives me the error :  `duplicate worksheet name 'sheet1'`

I understand that after the first iteration there is already a sheet named sheet1, but I don't know how I could solve this.

Comment: `sheet1 = wb.add_sheet('sheet'+number)`

Comment: doing this will give me the error : TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Comment: `sheet1 = wb.add_sheet('sheet'+str(number))`